# set value for property in func1, get value of property in func2 PHP7

Tags: php, class, properties

I am new to php7 and I am using MVC.
This is the story:
Server sends user a keyCode by Ajax (method A). Then user sends the keyCode by form to (method B). I have saved the keyCode to property named $beforCode in method A. Now I want to check the keyCode, which user sent me, in method B. BUT the problem is in method B I can't get the value of property keyCode which I have saved in method A. The property keyCode is empty.

here is my code:

```
class Payment extends Controller{

    public $keyCode = '';

    function setUserKeyCode(){ /// method A

        $code = $this->model->getKey();
        $this->keyCode = $code;

        /// echo $this->keyCode |  $this->keyCode equaled with $code
        echo $code; /// user get this by AJAX
    }


    function checkKeyCode(){ /// method B

         $userSentCode = $_POST['meKey']; /// user send this by Form
         $Key = $this->keyCode; /// echo $Key | $key = ''     <--- problem

         if ($clientCode == $key ) {
             echo 'user is valid';
         } 
         else {
             echo 'user is NON-valid';
         }
    }

}
```

*****If anybody has any other way to apply this job, please tell me.
thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you ajax action and the user's post action are not in the same process, PHP use different processes for different requests. It's not the same Payment object so you can not get the key.

For your problem, I suggest saving the key value to the session.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["code"]=$code;
```

And getting it :

```
session_start();
$code = $_SESSION["code"];
```

Comment: thanks a lot and your suggestion helped me. But I am looking for some like global variable or etc. Tnx anyway ;)

Comment: As far as I know, global variable won't help for this case, because the processes are different. Maybe if you share the details of what you are trying to achieve and why you can not use session, I can give better suggestion.